# How to differentiate if parent and child division having same css class name on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Actually my requirement is to create dynamic division(mupliple div's). while creating i'm adding the class name(.cellhandle).
 here i want hover of each division (div) i need to show some content.

for example:

```
CSS: while creating


 .cellhandle {
        display: none;      
      }
```

I want to change  while hovering to

```
.cellhandle {
      display: block;
  }
```

Now my division (div's) are like following:

```
<div class='normalcellstyle '> 
        <div class='cellhandle'> </div>
        <div class='cellhandle'> </div>
        <div class='cellhandle'>
            <div class='cellhandle'> </div>
            <div class='cellhandle'>
                <div class='cellhandle'> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

How can i get which cell handle is hovering i need to change to particular only.
       Currently all the div's getting hovered technically it's correct. but i want to achive this.
       Anyone please help me to achive this.

Currently i am doing like this:

```
.webnormalcellstyle:hover .cellhandle {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Can you use seperate id's ?

Comment: If an element is `display: none` you cannot hover over it. Do you mean `visibility: hidden` instead?

Comment: @AbhishekVAshok why would you want to do that? Using a common class is absolutely fine, and would seem to be ideal for this situation

Comment: Well. how do you hover without it being displayed?

Comment: @AbhishekVAshok - Not possible because i 'm creating all the div's dynamically. and if i will add id + (incremental value) how i will assign hover for each id. if it's static code then i can do code. here i don't how many div's will come. this is completely end-user hand.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Now please have a look my html code. when ever i'm hovering on 'normalcellstyle ' then cellhandle should display.

Comment: @bagya if I understood you right, you need to hide the particular `cellhandle` div you hover ??

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa - No Actually i need show when ever i'm hovering it.

Comment: Alright, so what about the `cellhandle` divs inside the one you hovered on ? those should be shown as well or only the one you hovered

Comment: Not clear. `normalcellstyle` and  `cellhandle` are the same element. How can you hide it and still be able to hover? (that's why you still don't have answer after 15 mins, because it's not clear)

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa - cellhandle is not separete div it added with <div class='normalcellstyle cellhandle'> </div>

Comment: @dfsq - I am not hiding normalcellstyle div ... I'm only hiding cellhandle  content. so when ever hover is happening on normalcellstyle  then i have to display cellhandle  content. I think clearing your doubt

Comment: Firstly there are couple of definite change you need to do - If you want to be able to hover while hiding it, you can't have `display: none`. `display: none` completely removes that element (meaning you cannot hover on something that is not there). Use `visibility: hidden;` instead

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa - Sorry.. normalcellstyle  and  cellhandle having different division(div's). here parent div is  'normalcellstyle'  child div is 'cellhandle '. I changed html code above . please have look at that and please give me the suggestion

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - even if `visibility: hidden;` you cannot hover on hidden elements. Only by wrapping that hidden element within another container(which is not hidden) would do.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa very true. `opacity` would possibly be a better solution in that case: https://jsfiddle.net/80ekm6ta/1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes I agree.

Comment: Yeah i can try with opacity

Comment: yes, I have shown it below how to use that as well. Try both and play around

Comment: I tried what ever ways you guys suggested...but nothing is working for my requiremnt. here the link for my actual https://jsfiddle.net/80ekm6ta/2/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned there are couple of changes you need to make

First, change the styling to `visibility: hidden;` You cannot hover on something that is not present in the first place. Even if its hidden you still cannot hover it unless you wrap it within another division(you already did this, so good). But change the styling as below. ie.

```
 .cellhandle {
     visibility: hidden;      
  }
```

Next, give some content to the divisions(`.cellhandle`). How will you realize whether the contents are even being displayed on hover when they are empty.

```
<div class='normalcellstyle'> 
  <div class='cellhandle'>give</div>
  <div class='cellhandle'>some</div>
  <div class='cellhandle'>
    values
    <div class='cellhandle'>here</div>
    <div class='cellhandle'>
      to
      <div class='cellhandle'>verify</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next use jquery to show **on hover of `.normalcellstyle`**

```
$('.normalcellstyle').hover(function () {
  $(this).find('.cellhandle').css({ visibility: 'visible' });
});
```

Check [this codepen here](https://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/KmZPVZ)

**OR** like Rory mentioned above, you could just use `opacity`(no Jquery needed for this)

```
.cellhandle {
   opacity: 0;      
}

.normalcellstyle:hover .cellhandle {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

Comment: I tried what ever ways you suggested...but nothing is working for my requirement. here the link for my actual https://jsfiddle.net/80ekm6ta/2/.

Comment: It is behaving as told, can you tell me what would you want to see in the example given?

Comment: I want to show that icons on hover of particular div  which is having .cellhandle. now it's showing for all

Comment: @bagya - the HTML was wrong, there were no closing divs in the right places. I have updated the JSFiddle to get it working which you can find here - https://jsfiddle.net/80ekm6ta/4/

Comment: No HTML is correct only. that is the my requirement. Actually cell inside container and inside that container two cells. Here  all cell having css (.webnormalcellstyle) with cell handle. in this case i need to achive on hover of particular cell. please help on this. if you're still not clear please let me know i will try to elaborate more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are multiple divs not having closing tags (`</div>`) correct ? Your structure is fine but the **syntax is wrong**. This is what i meant by HTML is wrong syntactically

Comment: Regarding the most recent fiddle, a container should be wrapping ONLY the `.cellhandle` div and NOT the entire HTML. Your `.webnormalcellstyle` is wrapping the entire HTML & that's the problem. You are basically hovering over the entire html this way and not just the ones you want which wont work. To avoid this, wrap your `.cellhandle` by a container and apply hover on that. Updated [here](https://jsfiddle.net/80ekm6ta/7/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But i can't add extra div..because i'm using angular directive anyhow i will play using your idea...once again thanks

Comment: Well if you can't even edit the HTML then only JQuery can save you in this case. Updated the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/80ekm6ta/8/) just the way you want.